# Azure CI pipeline build error while building Xcode project

Tags: xcode, firebase, azure-devops, cocoapods

I am trying to set up a CI pipeline using Azure DevOps and i am getting an error as follows while running the pipeline in the xcode section:

```
'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>

'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
Finishing: Xcode
```

A small part of my `podfile` is as follows:

```
#Firebase
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '~> 4.3'
```

And my `azure-pipelines.yml` file looks like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: true
    projectDirectory: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'pod install using the CocoaPods task with a forced repo update and a custom project directory'
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: ''
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath
```

I was been trying to get it solved by trying many fixes, but nothing helped. And now i don't know what to do. I would be really satisfied if anyone helps me out in this.

Comment: How about the result when you build in your local without Azure devops? And have you tried remove the use_frameworks from the pod file, while using a 1.5+ version of cocoa pods, and adding the :modular_headers => true for specific pods which depend on Obj-C code.https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1166#issuecomment-432772289

Comment: OP - Did it work? Were you able to build your application? We're having the same issue.

Comment: Yes i was able to build my application successfully